# Assign a TouchUpInside event to several UIImageViews via a loop, with a handler method that can further animate/manipulate each UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I've looped through an NSArray of NSDictionary objects that contain the data for several images to be displayed. This data is then converted into UIImageView objects and added to the current view as subviews. Simple enough! All the images passed in via the array/dict are displayed on the screen as desired, and it works great so far:

```
for (NSDictionary *caseData in caseImages) { // caseImages is the array
    UIImage *caseImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[caseData objectForKey:@"image_file"]];
    UIImageView *caseView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:caseImage];
    caseView.frame = CGRectMake([[caseData objectForKey:@"position_x"] intValue], [[caseData objectForKey:@"position_y"] intValue], [[caseData objectForKey:@"size_w"] intValue], [[caseData objectForKey:@"size_h"] intValue]);
    [self.view addSubview:caseView ];
}
```

However, now I need to take this a step further, and implement a touchUpInside event handler that can be attached to each of these UIImageView objects if possible, in such a way that the handler method can further animate/manipulate each UIImageView, ideally centering and enlarging the touched image, and simply fading the rest of the images out.

Where I'm stuck is on how to successfully add the touch events, with the ability to reference the image that case touched, as well as the rest of the untouched images if possible, and then apply the proper transition animations to each image respectively.

I have seen examples similar to the snippet below, but I haven't been able to get it working:

```
[caseView addTarget:self action:@selector(spotlightCase) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Although, had I actually gotten it to work, I'd still feel a bit left in the dark about how to successfully reference each and every UIImageView created from the loop, so each image could be animated/manipulated properly according to which one had indeed been touched. Would I need a new array property in my view controller that would hold the pointers for each UIImageView object added to the view? Is none of this even accomplishable with UIImageViews? I saw someone mention using custom UIButton objects, but I thought that might be equally complicated/impossible seeing as I also need to animate the size and location of the images anyway.

Any chance you can shed some insight on how to implement all of the tricky endeavors above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add a UIButton to your view controller's view for each image and set the backgroundImage property to the `[UIImage imageNamed:]` inside your loop.  You can set a generic selector to the target of each button just like in your second snippet.  I have used a similar trick before and set the tag property of the button to identify the index of the button that was pressed.  If you also add a colon to the end of your `@selector(spotlightCase:)` your method will also get passed the id of the object that called it.  Your method definition would be:

```
- (void) spotlightCase:(id) sender;
```

This is where you can use the `sender.tag` to control your logic.

Hope this helps

Dave

Comment: Thanks Dave, very helpful info. If I were to go this route, then would I apply the desired animations/manipulations to those UIImage objects that would be getting set as the backgroundImage properties to the UIButton objects?

Comment: Then how would I also handle fading the UIImages/UIButtons that don't get touched? Would I still need to store references to each UIImage/UIButton in an array so I could loop them all again in the 'spotlightCase' handler method? I imagine I could probably do quite a bit with them as far as animation/manipulation goes, so long as I somehow maintain a reference/pointer to each UIImage/UIButton somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I would create a mutable array of UIButtons and add them to the array as you create them.  In your spotlightCase method you can iterate through the array, if it the pointer to the object matches the one touched (the sender) then do one thing, if not do something else. Hope that makes sense, Dave.

Comment: Nice. Well what I ended up doing instead, since I only wanted to fade the other UIButtons, I simply created a new UIImageView with the image used for the touched UIButton, then I added it to the view, right on top of the touched UIButton, and applied my animations to that instead of the button. Then, in the same animation block, I added a new UIView with a white background, and animated it from 0.0 to 1.0 opacity, giving the impression that the other UIButtons are fading out. Works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting value to caseImage.tag and use that to identify the image that has been touched.